# Left aligning and breaking equations in cases environment

Tags: equations, align, cases

I have a equation that needs to be left aligned within the `cases` environment. Here's my code so far, which does **not** work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:algin} 
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
u_i^{k+1}(x)=\arg \min_{u} \Bigg\{
{}& \lambda\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega} r_i(x)u_i(x)\diff x 
+ \frac{\gamma}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega} \left( u_i(x)-m(x) \right)^2\diff x 
+ \frac{\mu}{2}\int_{\Omega} \left( u_i(x)-m(x) \right)^2\diff x
\Bigg\},
\\
f'(x_{0})=0 \text{ : } z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
\\
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty \text{ : } x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
\\
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} \text{ : } z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

My wrong output is:
[image]

I'm trying to get output like this:

[image]

This is my expected result

[image]

Thanks egreg. I found that when equation is so long (we cut it before), the equation number will automatically locate in bottom. Could we can relocate it in middle? 
Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
u_i^{k+1}(x)
\!\begin{multlined}[t]
=\frac{-\lambda r_i(x)+\gamma \bigl( r_i(x)+b_i(x)\bigr)+\gamma \bigl( \alpha-\beta\bigr)}{\theta}\\
 -\frac{\sigma \bigl( -\lambda\int_{i=1}^N r_i(x) \diff x + \sigma\sum_{i=1}^N \bigl( r_i(x)-b_i(x)\bigr) +\gamma N \bigl( 1-r_i(x)\bigr)\bigr)}{\gamma\bigl( \sigma N -1\bigr)},
\end{multlined}
\\[1ex]
f'(x_{0})=0 : z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty : x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} : z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
This is text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @macro: I did not use it, Do you tried to use it?

Comment: I've posted an addendum to my answer to address your follow-up query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `mathtools` and its `dcases` and `multlined` environments.

I propose two solutions; the first avoids an ambiguity in your formulas, where the same index is used both as a bound and a free variable; the second one is similar to yours.

I removed the unnecessary `\left` and `\right`; changed `\Bigg` into `\biggl` and `\biggr`; changed `\text{ : }` into simple colons; defined `\argmin`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
u_j^{k+1}(x)=
  \!\begin{multlined}[t]
  \argmin_{u}
  \biggl\{
  \frac{\mu}{2}\int\limits_{\Omega} (u_j(x)-m(x))^2\diff x \\
  +\sum_{i=1}^{N}\biggl(
     \lambda\int\limits_{\Omega} r_i(x)u_i(x)\diff x 
     + \frac{\gamma}{2}\int\limits_{\Omega} (u_i(x)-m(x))^2\diff x
   \biggr)
  \biggr\},
  \end{multlined}
\\[1ex]
f'(x_{0})=0 : z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty : x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} : z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
\!\begin{aligned}[t]
u_j^{k+1}(x)&=
  \argmin_{u}
  \biggl\{
  \lambda\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega} r_i(x)u_i(x)\diff x \\
  &\quad+ \frac{\gamma}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega} (u_i(x)-m(x))^2\diff x 
  + \frac{\mu}{2}\int_{\Omega} (u_i(x)-m(x))^2\diff x
  \biggr\},
  \end{aligned}
\\[1ex]
f'(x_{0})=0 : z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty : x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
\\[1ex]
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} : z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. However, the whole equations stills not left align. It looks like in centering

Comment: @user8430 You should use the `fleqn` option to `amsmath` (or to the document class), if you want lft aligned equations. I see no reason for having just one equation left aligned: either all or none.

Comment: How to just align the above equation? Because it is long equation so I would like to align it to left. Could you edit your answer for that work? Note that, other equation still centering

Comment: @user8430 I don't understand why you'd want that. However, `\begin{equation}\hspace{0pt}\begin{dcases}...\end{dcases}\hfill\end{equation}` would do.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just ask you one more think. How you can change position of equation number (Ex. (1),(2)) from bottom to middle?

Comment: @user8430 That's another question that needs a full example.

Comment: I think no because someone has same problem as some ans. of some guy in my question. The number does not align to middle

Comment: @user8430 Well, here it is in the middle, isn't it?

Comment: I found that when the equation so long (although we cut it), the equation number will auto move to the end of equation. Let see my update

Comment: @user8430 If there's not enough space for the equation number, because the equation is too wide, the number is moved down. The equation in your edit *is* too wide.

Comment: So we have no solution for edited equation, right?

Comment: @user8430 No, unless you write it in a different way; long fractions are better written as `\frac{1}{<denominator>}\bigl(<numerator>\bigr)` (where `big` stands for any of the size specifiers) and so the splitting can occur in the numerator part.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to manually chose where the line break should occur:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:algin} 
\begin{cases}
u_i^{k+1}(x) =\arg \min_{u} \Bigg\{
{} \lambda\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega} r_i(x)u_i(x)\diff x \\
\qquad\qquad + \frac{\gamma}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega} \left( u_i(x)-m(x) \right)^2\diff x 
+ \frac{\mu}{2}\int_{\Omega} \left( u_i(x)-m(x) \right)^2\diff x
\Bigg\},
\\
f'(x_{0})=0 \text{ : } z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn.}
\\
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty \text{ : } x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn.}
\\
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} \text{ : } z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to maintain equation tag. Because I am using equation tag through my paper. And the number of equation regards to middle of equation position. And I run your code. It works well but it did not align left without space. For example, let see my image above, the $\{$ similar position with "where"

Comment: @user8430: Yeah, it should just use equation. Have updated solution.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my updated figure. The equation still not align in left and numbering of equation must be the center. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a `cases` environment; a `left\{` directive at the start and a `\right.` directive at the end of the `equation` environment requires much less computing overhead. Inside the `\left\{ ... \right.` pair, I'd use nested `aligned` instructions. The contents of `aligned` environments are automatically typeset in display-math style, which seems appropriate for the long (sub-)equation.

Incidentally, the inner `\left( ... \right)` directives in your code don't generate larger "fences", as the material they enclose isn't "large". I'd use `\bigl( ... \bigr)` instead.

(The horizontal line at the top of the following screenshot is there just to illustrate the width of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}
\hrule  % just to illustrate width of textblock
\begin{equation}\label{eq:algin} 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{aligned}
u_i^{k+1}(x)
&=\arg\min_{u} \Biggl\{
\lambda\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega}\! r_i(x)u_i(x)\diff x \\
&\mkern25mu % select spacing adjustment to suit your page parameters
+ \frac{\gamma}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Omega}\! \bigl( u_i(x)-m(x) \bigr)^2\diff x 
+ \frac{\mu}{2}\int_{\Omega}\! \bigl( u_i(x)-m(x) \bigr)^2\diff x
\Biggr\},
\end{aligned}\\
&f'(x_{0})=0 \text{ : $z=f(x_{0})$ is de horizontale raaklijn.}\\
&\lim_{\mathclap{x\to x_{0}}} \ f'(x)=\pm\infty \text{ : $x=x_{0}$ is de verticale raaklijn.}\\
&g(x_{0}){R}_{0} \text{ : $z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})$ is de raaklijn.}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up query about how to go about having the equation number be placed at the bottom of the equation: In this case, I would work first and foremost to shorten one or more of the lines in the `dcases` environment. This may be done, e.g., by rearranging the structure of the `multlined` environment that governs the first two lines.

While you're at it, you may also want to make sure that the material in the numerators and denominators of the first two lines is typeset in display-style math mode rather than the default text-style math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'dcases' and 'multlined' environments
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
% Variant form of \dfrac macro, which places both the numerator
% and the denominator in display math style
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
\begin{multlined} % let the 'multlined' environment encase both lines fully
u_i^{k+1}(x)
=\ddfrac{-\lambda r_i(x)+\gamma \bigl( r_i(x)+b_i(x)\bigr) +\gamma \bigl( \alpha-\beta\bigr)}{\theta}\\[2ex]
 -\ddfrac{\sigma \biggl[ -\lambda\int_{i=1}^N r_i(x) \diff x + \sigma\sum_{i=1}^N \bigl( r_i(x)-b_i(x)\bigr) +\gamma N \bigl( 1-r_i(x)\bigr)\biggr]}{\gamma\bigl( \sigma N -1\bigr)}\,,
\end{multlined}
\\[1ex]
f'(x_{0})=0 : z=f(x_{0}) \text{ is de horizontale raaklijn,}
\\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f'(x)=\pm\infty : x=x_{0} \text{ is de verticale raaklijn,}
\\[0.5ex]
g(x_{0}){R}_{0} : z-f(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})\cdot(x-x_{0})
  \text{ is de raaklijn.}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
This is text \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank, it worked but the cases { stills far left corner. Let see my expected output in question

Comment: I used packet \usepackage[dutch]{babel}, then my proof tag name becomes bewijs instead of Proofs:. For example   \begin{proof}
  This is text of proof
 \end{proof}

Comment: @user8430 - Using the `babel` package is definitely optional. I just thought it might be useful, since the text of your posting would appear to be in Dutch. If you'd rather not use the package, that's fine too.

Comment: If we use dutch, We cannot display in English. Right?

Comment: @user8430 - I'm not sure what you're trying to get at. The `babel` package can be loaded with several language options. If English is, in fact, the main document language (the code snippet you've provided notwithstanding), then by all means load the `babel` package with the option `english`.